# Как добавить в столбец данные, сохранив соответствие между уже имеющимися столбцами

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется dataframe, подобный данному:

```
  col1    col2 
0 20      489
1 40      528
2 50      662
```

Нужно получить это:

```
 col1    col2
0 10     0
1 20     489
2 30     0
3 40     528
4 50     662
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.reindex()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html).

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [27]: df
Out[27]:
   col1  col2
0    20   489
1    40   528
2    50   662
```

Решение:

```
import numpy as np

res = df.set_index('col1').reindex(np.arange(10, 60, 10), fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Результат:

```
In [29]: res
Out[29]:
   col1  col2
0    10     0
1    20   489
2    30     0
3    40   528
4    50   662
```